# How do I simultaneously select multiple values for k-means in WEKA?

Tags: clustering, weka

I have tried WEKA's Experimenter. However, it's for classification.

I'm looking for a way to apply the k-means algorithm on the same dataset but with multiple '**k**' values. Is there any option in WEKA's GUI allow this?

Comment: @knb "AddCluster" is not for what I'm asking. I just need a way to apply multiple k values on a dataset in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a program.

It's easy to do a for loop over k.

You will also want to use multiple random seeds.

Comment: @Anony-Mousses I know it's possible with programming. However, as my question says (in WEKA's GUI). Is it possible in WEKA's GUI?